# google app engine's ferris2.2 framework (python), uploading an image to cloud storage?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-storage, blobstore, image-upload

So.. This is my code for uploading an image with the Ferris2 frame work. Yay me, it works. However, see how I had to comment out gcs.open(... ? I don't want that commented out. I'd really love to just upload straight to cloud storage using that call, and not having to use anything related to blobs. What's the easiest way to  accomplish this given that I'm stuck with using the AClassForm and the ferris framework?

```
class AClassForm(forms.model_form(AClass, exclude=('image_url') ) ):
     image = FileField(u'Image File') 

class AClasses(Controller): 

    class Meta: 

        Model = AClass 

        prefixes = ('admin',) 

        components = (scaffold.Scaffolding, Upload) 

        Form = AClassForm 



    admin_list = scaffold.list 

    admin_view = scaffold.view 

    admin_edit = scaffold.edit 

    admin_delete = scaffold.delete 



    def admin_add(self): 

        self.scaffold.ModelForm = AClassForm 

        self.scaffold.form_encoding = "multipart/form-data"    

        def before_save_callback(controller,container, item): 

            image = self.request.params["image"] 

            object_name = blobstore.parse_file_info(image).gs_object_name.split('/')[-1] 

            upload_settings = settings.get("upload") 

            url =  upload_settings["url"] 

            bucket = upload_settings["bucket"] 

            #send to the cloud 

            #write a task to execute this? 

            item.image_url  =  url % (bucket, object_name) 

            #gcs_file= gcs.open("/".join(["", bucket, object_name]),   

               # 'w', content_type="image/jpeg",  

                #options={'x-goog-acl': 'public-read'} )  

            #gcs_file.write(item.image)#.file.encode('utf-8')) # 

            #gcs_file.close() 

            return 

        self.events.scaffold_before_save += before_save_callback 

        return scaffold.add(self)
```

Answer (score 0):

As I understand it, if you're using the Upload component of Ferris you can't escape the Blobstore, but the following comes pretty close.  You don't have to use the Form class if you don't want to, I rarely use it myself. So imagine the following Controller:

```
from ferris import Controller, route
from ferris.components.upload import Upload
import cloudstorage as gcs
from google.appengine.ext import blobstore
import logging


class ImageManager(Controller):
    class Meta:
        components = (Upload,)  

    @route
    def list(self):
        #This just passes the upload URL to use in the form
        self.context['upload_url'] = self.components.upload.generate_upload_url(uri=self.uri('image_manager:image_uploader_action'))


    @route
    def image_uploader_action(self):
        # This gets all of the uploads passed in from the form
        uploads = self.components.upload.get_uploads()

        # This is the raw google cloud object reference. 'myfile' is the name of the upload field in the html form
        file_gcs_obj_name = uploads['myfile'][0].cloud_storage.gs_object_name 

        # This is the blobstore key just for giggles
        file_blobstore_key = uploads['myfile'][0].key()

        # This will get rid of the preceeding junk you don't need i.e. "/gs/yadda/yadda"
        clean_file_name = file_gcs_obj_name[3:]

        # This is the name of the file as it was uploaded by the end-user
        file_name_friendly  = uploads['myfile'][0].filename

        # This is the actual file, with this you can do whatever you want
        the_actual_image = gcs.open(clean_file_name,'r')

        # The file name by default is long and ugly, lets make a copy of the file with a more friendly name
        new_filename = '/mydomain.appspot.com/'+file_name_friendly
        gcs.copy2(clean_file_name,new_filename)

        # We can generate a serving URL by using the blobstore API
        valid_blob_reference = blobstore.create_gs_key('/gs'+new_filename)
        file_serving_url = images.get_serving_url(valid_blob_reference)
        logging.info('the serving url is: %s'% file_serving_url)

        # delete the original image from cloud storage
        gcs.delete(clean_file_name)

        # Delete the original image from blobstore
        blobstore.delete(file_blobstore_key)

        # Close the file
        the_actual_image.close()

        return 'Done. go check the cloud storage browser'
```

Now all you need is the HTML form.  You can use something like this:

```
{% extends "layouts/default.html" %}
{% block layout_content %}
<form name="myform" action="{{upload_url}}" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" name="myfile" id="fileToUpload">
    <input type="submit" value="Upload File" name="submit">
</form>
{% endblock %}
```

Ferris is still going to place a file in the blobstore but you can delete it after you've used the cloudstorage.copy2() function.  That function is fairly new so remember to update your cloudstorage package, you can download the latest copy from Google or Pypi (https://pypi.python.org/pypi/GoogleAppEngineCloudStorageClient/1.9.22.1)
Hope this helps.

Comment: Seems like you did gcs.open,   but you never wrote the image, meaning gcs.write(?). Was that on purpose? Do you know if this code works?

Comment: You're absolutely right, the open was completely unnecessary in my example, because the Upload component already puts it in cloudstore. Only thing missing is generating a serving URL (which I updated) Definitely works used it today actually.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure how Ferris works internally but you can use `cloudstorage` directly.

My image storage wrapper, provides resizing and returns a public URL to the upload for serving directly from storage.

```py
import urlparse    
from google.appengine.api import app_identity, blobstore, images
import cloudstorage

class ImageStorage(object):

    def __init__(self, base_uri):
        self.base_uri = "/{}/{}".format(app_identity.get_default_gcs_bucket_name(), base_uri.lstrip('/'))

    def put(self, image, name, mime=None, width=None, height=None):
        """Puts an image into the Google Cloud Storage"""

        if width or height:
            image = images.resize(image, width=width or height, height=height or width)
            mime = 'image/png'  # resize defaults to output_encoding=PNG
        options = {'x-goog-acl': 'public-read'}
        with cloudstorage.open(self.make_key(name), 'w', content_type=mime, options=options) as fp:
            fp.write(image)
        return self.get_url(name)

    def get_url(self, name):
        """Gets the url for an image from Google Cloud Storage"""
        key = self.make_key(name)
        # must be prefixed with /gs for the blob store to know it is from gcs
        # https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/blobstore/#Python_Using_the_Blobstore_API_with_Google_Cloud_Storage
        url = images.get_serving_url(blobstore.create_gs_key('/gs' + key))

        # s/https/http/ if running under dev_appserver.py
        # if not config.isLocal:
        #    parts = urlparse.urlparse(url)
        #    secure_parts = ('https',) + parts[1:]
        #    url = urlparse.urlunparse(secure_parts)

        return url

    def make_key(self, name):
        """Makes an item name key for Google Cloud Storage"""
        return '%s/%s' % (self.base_uri, name)
```

Usage inside of a subclass of `webapp2.RequestHandler`. This stores the file with name "image" in the default bucket for your app in cloud storage at path `/some/bucket/path/my-image-name`.

```py
thumb = self.request.POST["image"]
if hasattr(thumb, 'value'):
    gs_base_uri = '/some/bucket/path'
    image_storage = ImageStorage(gs_base_uri)
    thumb_fn = 'my-image-name'
    session_thumb_url = image_storage.put(image=thumb.value,
                                          name=thumb_fn,
                                          mime=thumb.type,
                                          width=300, height=300)

    return session_thumb_url
```